# JsonDeserialize error in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to use JsonDeserialize class but the IDE is showing compilation error.

GateAnnotation.scala

```
package com.scryAnalytics.NLPAnnotationController.DAO

import com.scryAnalytics.NLPGeneric.DAO.FeatureMapDeserializer
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize
import gate.{FeatureMap, Node}
import gate.annotation.AnnotationImpl

/**
* Created by sahil on 22/11/16.
*/

class GateAnnotation(id: Integer, start: Node, end: Node, types: String, features: FeatureMap) extends
AnnotationImpl(id, start, end, types, features) {

private final  val serialVersionUID: Long = 1L
@JsonProperty
@JsonDeserialize(using = FeatureMapDeserializer.class)
}
```

FeatureMapDeserializer.scala

```
package com.scryAnalytics.NLPAnnotationController.DAO

import java.util.Map

import gate.{Factory, FeatureMap}
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet.HamletSpec._Object
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.{DeserializationContext, JsonDeserializer}

class FeatureMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer[FeatureMap] {

override def deserialize(jsonParser: JsonParser, deserializationContext: DeserializationContext): FeatureMap = {
val features = jsonParser.readValueAs(classOf[Map[_Object, _Object]])
val featureMap = Factory.newFeatureMap()
featureMap.putAll(features)
 featureMap
} 
}
```

The error (compilation) is **@JsonDeserialize(using = FeatureMapDeserializer.class)**.  The error after hovering over the line is **Expression of type FeatureMapDeserializer doesn't conform to expected type Class [ < JsonDeserializer[_]]**

I can't figure out the reason, so I look forward to any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste the full result of sbt compile pls

Answer (score 1):

You're using Java syntax, not Scala one.

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonDeserialize(using = classOf[FeatureMapDeserializer])
def foo = ???
```

Comment: I did the same, now the error displayed is "Cannot resolve JsonDeserialize.apply"

Comment: @wadhwasahil Is it a runtime error, or did `FeatureMapDeserializer` make it?

Comment: It is a compilation error I guess. And on @JsonProperty line , it says "Definition or declaration expected"

Comment: @wadhwasahil Could you check annotations' target? It would be `def foo = ???` in my code, which yours doesn't have. I just thought you skipped it to make it short.